# How to set system-wide preference in Android?

Tags: android

I have written a native daemon that communicates with system apps through a local named socket. However, I was wondering how the native daemon can interact with system-wide preferences or any preference reserved for privileged processes?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

So, I did figure out how to do this and thought I'd share how.

There are multiple viable options. You could write a custom preference file and store it in an appropriate directory that your daemon and apps have access to, or you could use system properties, which is what I did. It worked well because during testing I could use setprop/getprop commands to modify the values.

There are file locations you can use to set up the default properties on startup:

- /default.prop
- /system/build.prop
- /system/default.prop
- /data/local.prop